AWK or alternative way to join (and occasionally correct) two fields in csv
A little while I ago I started writing something to parse some application logs and thought everything was well but today I noticed some data missing and it's because of a timestamp issue. The log structure is like this:
f_timestamp,f_timestamp2,f_date
1729448207,303701614,2024/10/20 19:16:47 303701614
1729415974,96090458,2024/10/20 19:16:47 096090458

I need nano second precision, what I was doing was crudely gluing f_stampstamp and f_timestamp2 together
awk -F ',' '{print $0 FS $1$2}' filein.csv > fileout.csv

Problematic result:
f_timestampf_timestamp2
1729448207303701614
172941597496090458

Problem is that f_timestamp2 is sometimes 8 digits - the leading 0 means my dates are months out
Expected result is
f_timestampf_timestamp2
1729448207303701614
1729415974096090458

There are two ways I know of out of this problem

Find a way to add the leading 0 when necessary i.e. f_timestamp2 < 9 digits
Convert f_date to YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.sssssssss format since this is what my database expects for timestamps and forget about the unix timestamps. The format of f_date differs in later versions but I can work around that.


the hardest part of your question is "(and occasionally correct)". Why only occasionally ???

your code shows printing the current input line plus the new compound column, while the expected result is showing just the new compound column; please confirm that you only want to generate the new compound column, or update the wrong/correct results to include the input columns as well

Append new column (f_timestamp + 0-padded f_timestamp2)
One awk idea using sprintf("%09d", ...) to left pad f_timestamp2 / $2 with zero's:
awk '
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }
      { print $0, $1 (NR==1 ? $2 : sprintf("%09d", $2)) }
' filein.csv

Another awk idea using a dual input delimiter (command and space) so we can make use of the last field which is already 0-padded:
awk '
BEGIN { FS = "[, ]"; OFS = "," }
      { print $0, $1 (NR==1 ? $2 : $NF) }
' filein.csv

Both of these generate:
f_timestamp,f_timestamp2,f_date,f_timestampf_date
1729448207,303701614,2024/10/20 19:16:47 303701614,1729448207303701614
1729415974,96090458,2024/10/20 19:16:47 096090458,1729415974096090458


Reformat f_date to YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.sssssssss
One idea using sed to make the edits:
$ sed 's#/#-#g; s# #.#2' filein.csv

Where:

since our data includes the forward slash (/) we'll use # as our sed script delimiter
s#/#-#g - replace all forward slashes (/) with hyphens (-)
s# #.#2 - replace 2nd occurrence of a space with a period

This generates:
f_timestamp,f_timestamp2,f_date
1729448207,303701614,2024-10-20 19:16:47.303701614
1729415974,96090458,2024-10-20 19:16:47.096090458


Use zero padding.
awk -F ',' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS }
    { $(NF+1) = sprintf("%i%0.9i", $1, $2)} 1' filein.csv > fileout.csv


I thought the .9 in %0.9i already makes the 0 implicit ?

Using split on the f_date column
awk -F',' 'NR==1{print "f_timestampf_timestamp2"}
           NR>1{split($3,arr," "); print $1 arr[3]}' file
f_timestampf_timestamp2
1729448207303701614
1729415974096090458


print $1""arr[3] = print $1 arr[3], the "" is doing nothing.


There are two ways I know of out of this problem

Find a way to add the leading 0 when necessary i.e. f_timestamp2 < 9 digits
Convert f_date to YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.sssssssss format since this is what my database expects for timestamps and forget about the unix
timestamps. The format of f_date differs in later versions but I can
work around that.


There is another one, just do not use concatenation but treat them as numbers and use arithmetic. I would harness GNU AWK following way, let file.csv content be
f_timestamp,f_timestamp2,f_date
1729448207,303701614,2024/10/20 19:16:47 303701614
1729415974,96090458,2024/10/20 19:16:47 096090458

then
awk -M 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}FNR==1{print $0,"f_mastertimestamp";next}{print $0, ($1*1000000000)+$2}' file.csv

gives output
f_timestamp,f_timestamp2,f_date,f_mastertimestamp
1729448207,303701614,2024/10/20 19:16:47 303701614,1729448207303701614
1729415974,96090458,2024/10/20 19:16:47 096090458,1729415974096090458

Explanation: I inform GNU AWK that it needs to deals with big numbers (-M) and that , is both field separator and output field separator. For first line I print headers as is followed by f_mastertimestamp (adjust to your needs). Then for each line I print line as-is ($0) followed by 1000000000 (as nano is 10^-9) times 1st field plus 2nd field.
(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)

Here is a Ruby to that:
ruby -r CSV -e '
puts CSV.parse($<.read).
    map{|row| row[0..1].map{|e| e.rjust(9, "0") }.join } 
' file.csv

Prints:
f_timestampf_timestamp2
1729448207303701614
1729415974096090458

Or use Ruby to convert the time stamp:
ruby -r CSV -r "time" -e '
CSV.parse($<.read).each.with_index{|row, i|
    if i==0 
        puts row[0]+row[1]
    else
        tz="-04:00"
        puts Time.at(row[0].to_i, row[1].to_i, :nsec, in: tz) 
    end
}' file.csv   

Prints:
f_timestampf_timestamp2
2024-10-20 14:16:47 -0400
2024-10-20 05:19:34 -0400

You just need to supply the correct time zone for that.

If you can make the assumption 3rd column f_date always matches the rest of the data in same row, then you can skip the padding concern and just do :
 echo 
'f_timestamp,f_timestamp2,f_date
 1729448207,303701614,2024/10/20 19:16:47 303701614
 1729415974,96090458,2024/10/20 19:16:47 096090458' | 


 awk 'NF = _++ ? NF : _+_' FS=',(.+ )?' OFS=


f_timestampf_timestamp2
1729448207303701614
1729415974096090458

if you're always sure 1st row is never empty, you can even make it
awk 'NF -= !_++' FS=',(.+ )?' OFS=


f_timestampf_timestamp2
1729448207303701614
1729415974096090458

The !_++ counter serves the role of identifying 1st row for special handling.
